# HCI: make the user wait through everything up front, or amortize?

Tags: silverlight, user-experience

I'm writing a silverlight app that queries a web service to populate a tree control.  Each element will have at least 2 levels of children, so something like this:

```
a
+-b
  +-c
d
+-g
  +-h
e
+-i
  +-j
f
+-k
  +-l
```

The web service API is such that I can only get one level of child nodes at a time, so the first trip, I can get a,d,e,f.  To get b,g,i,k, I have to make 4 trips.  Similarly, I have to make 4 more trips to get c,h,j,l.  (The service does actually allow me to get all the nodes in one trip, but it doesn't give me parent-child relationships along with it :-()

My question is this:  should I make the user wait for a while up front while I get all the nodes for the tree view, or should I just get the top few nodes, and get the other nodes on-demand, or in a background task?  Also, the nodes can change asynchronously, so if I get all the nodes up front, I'll need a "refresh" button for the treeview, and if I do it on demand, I'll have to have a caching strategy.

Which is best for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compromise where you load the first level up front and then load the remaining items in the background overridden by on-demand as required.  If you load the nodes breadth first (e.g. a,d,e,f then b,g,i,k) rather than depth first (e.g. a,d,e,f followed by b,c) you can redirect your loading to be focused on the most recently expanded node.

Comment: That's not a bad idea.  I was already doing breadth first, but I like the idea of an background thread that loads automatically, but superseded by user demand.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, as a user, I would prefer all the data to be loaded up front so that once the application finishes loading I can trust that I won't have to wait anymore (or at least very little)

But, I suppose it depends on several traits of your application / data:

- ***How dynamic is the data? Does it update more often then the rate at which the user explores the nodes?***  If it does, then you will have to read the data as the user explores it, otherwise you can probably get away with only updating it occasionally and checking for the freshest data before performing important operations.
- ***How much of the data will the user explore during normal use?***  If they are constantly exploring throughout the entire tree, then having the entire tree loaded is important.  On the other hand, if most users will usually only expand a small portion of the tree, then maybe loading on demand is better so you don't waste thier time loading data they will never see anyway.
- ***How much affect with this have on performance?  Does it really take a long time to load all the data?***  If the data is not too much, maybe the whole thing can be loaded in a matter of seconds, in which case the amount of work to implement the optimization will not be significant to the end user and in turn will not have a good return on investment.

Most likely you don't have clear cut answers to these questions, but they're probably good to consider when you're attacking this interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is to make the user wait for as little as possible. They will curse your name if they have to wait 10-20 seconds on application load, but not notice 0.1-0.2 seconds for a tree node to expand.

I have an app in production with a similar structure. I cannot load up-front because it'd be effectively loading the entire database. Here's my strategy:

- The tree control starts with 1 level expanded below the root.
- Each unexpanded node has a dummy child node in order to get the [+] expansion icon to show
- When a node is expanded, it fires an event which is trapped by the app. If the only child node is the dummy one, the dummy is deleted and the children are loaded from the database.
- Changes in the data are not reflected automatically by visible nodes, however the context menu for the tree has a Refresh item that can be used to refresh a node.

I have considered showing updates asynchronously, but have tended to avoid it because large amounts of data can be shown in the tree and I'm wary of DB load if I'm checking them all for changes.

The app is WinForms, written in C# using .NET 2.0.